# Jmeter reports for functional testing

Tags: jmeter, report

I am using Jmeter for functional testing and not just for load testing.
All the examples that I see for reports are for load testing, and I do not see how it is effective for functional, I do not care speed of response latency and so on.
I care about sampler response, is http get 200 OK, is the assertion succeed or not
the response message that I write, the JDBC response with my response message.
Is their a way to use Jmeter reports to see al that?
I have a test plan with 50 tests, is their any example of how it should look like in reports? 
Once again not care for this test from performance or load at all, just functional, Is their any guide since all the info I see its about performance and not functional

Answer (score 1):

You should look into Jmeter+ant integration. You can run .jmx files using Ant and generate HTML report. The HTML report gives the success and failure rate and response message as well.

[image]
Steps to run JMeter .jmx with Ant:

1. Install Apache Ant and the installation should be in your path.
2. Copy your .jmx file into your apache JMeter's /extras folder and replace existing Test.jmx file your own.
3. Type the command `ant`.
4. Ant will generate the .jtl and .html file with the same name as your .jmx file.
5. If you want to run the tests using continuous integration and Jenkins. Please follow the below nice blog.

   - http://www.testautomationguru.com/jmeter-continuous-performance-testing-part1/

Comment: But if for instance I have 3  steps in each test, and when I run the test plan it is not stop if one assertion is failed, how can I see it, I want in report to see all the steps and all the data in response message, not just test passed or failed, if I have a complex test with 20 steps, and 6 steps failed I would like to know why,

Comment: P.S can I create HTML report regardless the ANT? since I know that it is built in since Jmeter 3.0

Comment: If you want to see the live reporting of yours tests then you should check https://github.com/Blazemeter/taurus. At the runtime you can see the results. From taurus, you can also access the blazemeter reports. Check if that helps.

Comment: All I want is a report with thread group name, step name, if the step failed or not, step results (if it is JDBC), step response message, step assertion error message.   All this data is in Jmeter UI "view results tree" sampler, I just want to display it, in CSV all the data above

Answer (score 0):

You should check the 
for example for each listener you can click `Configure` and choose [Save   Configuration](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Sample_Result_Save_Configuration), in your case you can check only

1. `Save Success` - if it succeeded or failed
2. Save Field Names (CSV) - header line
3. Save Label - to know which request succeeded or failed

if no checkbox is checked you will get an empty lines for each sampler

[image]

You will get results as

```
label,success
HTTP Request,true
HTTP Request,true
HTTP Request2,false
HTTP Request2,false
```

Comment: I marked "Response message" so I expected to see it, In UI I entered to view response in table sampler, and not see this coloumn, is their a way to display all sampler responses, regardless success or error in Jmeter? I want to investigate nightly run but can not, since all data is time/latency and not functional, I want to see in each test its results the response message that I customized, how can I modify Jmeter to display it in reports ? currently soloution is to run all tests and wait couple of hours and than navigate manually each test and investigate

Answer (score 0):

You can precisely control what is being saved into .jtl results file by using dedicated JMeter Properties which names start from `jmeter.save.saveservice`

Example configuration will look like

```
jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml
jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data.on_error=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.bytes=true
#etc.
```

This way you will get a .jtl results file in .XML format which can be examined using [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener.

You can also view this .jtl file directly in browser, however you will need to add one line to it in order to specify the desired XSL stylesheet to it like:

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="C:\apache-jmeter-3.3\extras\jmeter-results-report_21.xsl"?>
```

More information: [Visualizing JMeter .jtl Files Viewed as An .xsl Stylesheet](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/visualizing-jmeter-jtl-files-viewed-xsl-stylesheet)